# Cannot convert string into DateTime

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to convert this date: `25/08/2016 10:45`
into DateTime using this:

```
$time = strtotime('25/08/2016 10:45');
$newformat = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
```

but I get `false` from `time`, why?

Comment: Dates of that style with a `/` separator are treated as US format (`mm/dd/yyyy`); for UK/European dates, use a `-` separator (`dd-mm-yyyy`); and `25/08/2016` is an invalid US date, because there is no month 25

Comment: PS, You're trying to convert to a unix timestamp, not to a [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: You can also use http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php if the format is fixed.

Comment: @MarkBaker I get `500 Internal server error` with createFromFormat

Comment: If you get a 500 internal server error, check your logs.... what version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', '25/08/2016 10:45');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```